# Footer is not on the bottom of the page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a webpage using Twitter Bootstrap Framework. I have a footer here and it is on the bottom of the page of every page with a lot of content. But I just created another sub-page and the footer is in the middle of the page like this: http://gyazo.com/45232ab25cdeb7705f9775a969051233.

I need to pull the footer on the bottom of the page.

Here is the adress to the page: http://tomas-nosek.moxo.cz/obsahmp.html.

How to pull the footer down?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to your footer CSS

```
footer {
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The given Example by anstosa will only bind the footer to the position where your browser ends as you entered the Homepage, it will maybe overlay some other Content that way if the content of the website expands.

So just fill your page with more content and/or use min-height on your content-div so you pushing the footer down. If I missread and you want it to be locked at the bottom of the page - then its okay that way ( In general you never use Positioning for regular floating content!)